# Substitute title with logo in a Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, title

I'm trying to upload a logo to the header of a website instead of the simple title. The theme I'm using is Yoko (with a few changes) and I tried in any way, but for some reason it doesn't work...

Here's the header's child theme code:

```js
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Yoko
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page" class="clearfix">
 <header id="branding">
  <nav id="mainnav" class="clearfix">
   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
  </nav><!-- end mainnav -->
  <?php global $yoko_options;
  $yoko_settings = get_option( 'yoko_options', $yoko_options ); ?>

  <hgroup id="site-title">
  <?php if( $yoko_settings['custom_logo'] ) : ?>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" on class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $yoko_settings['custom_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
  <?php else : ?>
   <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">hook<span>ii</span><?php
/* bloginfo( 'name' ); */
?></a></h1>
    <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </hgroup><!-- end site-title -->

     <div class="clear"></div>

  <nav id="subnav">
   <?php
   if (is_nav_menu( 'Sub Menu' ) ) {
   wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Sub Menu' ));} ?>
  </nav><!-- end subnav -->
</header><!-- end header -->
</header><!-- end header -->
```

I tried simply substituting the  with img tags, too.

Comment: You need to include the output with this as well or we don't know what it's returning.

If an h1 link to the homepage is being displayed instead of your image, then $yoko_settings['custom_logo'] is returning false, which either means you don't have your settings right in your theme options, or you aren't setting up this code right.

Comment: Hi Brian, the site is hookii.it
I didn't notice that it was returning false, I guess this is because the person who previously took care of the site did override the header image that was normally present in the theme.

Comment: Okay looking at your live site it definitely looks like it's returning false. Somewhere in your theme options there should be an option to use a logo in the header instead of the title. This may be separate from where you actually specify what image to use. Can you verify that it is set to display the logo and not a title?

Comment: Found it! Thank you for suggesting it again, yesterday I was too tired to notice it...
Now I only need to find a way to make visible again the scrolling subtitle, but this is a big step! 
Thanks.